# Writing to default-constructed fstream: Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

Consider the following:

```
std::basic_fstream<char> testfile;
testfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&someInt), sizeof(int));
testfile.close();
```

This runs with no complaint when built with VC 8.0, but crashes when built with VC 10.0 beta.

I have some legacy code that actually relies on the VC 8 behavior, where we inherit from basic_fstream to add functionality:

```
class myFile : public basic_fstream<char> {
    public:
    void myWrite(const char* data, std::streamsize len) {
       write(data, len);
       // update some state variables (checksum, etc)
    }
};
```

There are cases where it is beneficial to inspect the additional state without incurring the disk I/O (e.g. test writes).

I'm assuming this is undefined behavior, and I'm lucky it doesn't crash in VC 8.  That said, I've had enough issues evaluating VS 2010 beta that I'd like to be sure.  Can anyone out there say definitively?

EDIT: Call stack in VS 2010:

```
ostream::write
ostream::sentry ctor
istream::_Sentry_base ctor
fstream::_Lock
_file.c::_lock_file
crashes on EnterCriticalSection( &(((_FILEX *)pf)->lock) ), pf is null
```

Call stack on VS 2005:

```
ostream::write
ostream::sentry ctor
ostream::_Sentry_base ctor // different
streambuf::_Lock
_Mutex::_Lock()
_Mtxlock in xmtx.c
EnterCriticalSection(_Mtx), where _Mtx is valid
```

Also, compiles and runs with no errors with gcc-4.3.3 on Ubuntu.

*** EDIT:

After more digging, it appears that this in fact is a bug in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=456890

According to this report, it has been fixed for the official release.

Thanks for all of your input.

Comment: I only know for sure it's not UB to write into a ostream that was given a null pointer as rdbuf: ostream os(0); os << "hello"; is valid, because any output operation first checks the badbit, and won't do anything in that case. If the stream is initialized by a null pointer as the buffer, then it sets the badbit. (Some functions also explicitly test the value of rdbuf(). I tried to lookup how this behaves for file streams back then, but i didn't come to a conclusion iirc. Though, many functions say "if there is an output sequence, ..." which seems to allow having the file stream not opened.

Comment: Oh yes.... undefined behaviour!

Comment: Did you actually crash the program or did it just throw `ios_base::failure`?

Comment: Can someone close this question?  I updated it with a link to the Microsoft bug report, which I think sufficiently answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked whether throwing exceptions are enabled when the stream state is set to fail or bad? Because the C++ Standard says the following abt 'write' methdod :-

> 27.6.2.7. Unformatted output functions
>
> Point:-5
>
> `basic_ostream& write(const char_type* s, streamsize n);`
>
> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted
>   output function (as described in
>   27.6.2.7, paragraph 1). After constructing a sentry object, obtains
>   characters to insert from successive
>   locations of an array whose first
>   element is designated by s.
>   Characters are inserted until either
>   of the following occurs:

- n characters are inserted;
- inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the function calls setstate badbit), which may throw ios_base::failure (27.4.4.3)).

This means that at most `testfile.fail()` returns true. It should ideally not crash.
I suspect an exception is being thrown and not caught (But maybe i am totally wrong).

Comment: ios_base::failure is not being thrown.  The error is a null pointer dereference.

Interestingly, the call stack in VS 2010 looks like:
ostream::write
ostream::sentry constructor
istream::_Sentry_base constructor
fstream::_Lock
_lock_file in _file.c
in here it crashes on call to EnterCriticalSection(&(((_FILEX *)pf)->Lock()
pf is null

In VS 2005, however, the call stack looks like:
ostream::write
ostream::sentry ctor
ostream::_Sentry_base ctor
streambuf::_Lock()
_Mutex::_Lock()
_Mtxlock in xmtx.c
EnterCriticalSection(_Mtx), where _Mtx is valid

Comment: Wow, don't know what happened to my formatting there, edited the post instead.

Comment: @Ryan: It semms a little strange to me. Why is the runtime trying to lock istream when it should be locking ostream. May be you can try `std::basic_ofstream<char>` instead of `std::basic_fstream<char>`.

Comment: @Abnay: See my answer below, as you suspect it is a bug in VS's implementation.  Thanks for your help.